# Heroku "Could not find a required file. Name: index.html"

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have been running into this error "Could not find a required file. Name: index.html" when I attempt to deploy my React Portfolio to Heroku. I have looked at previous answers and I have not found a solution. I do not have my public folder in .gitignore and I will attach a photo to show. [image: file snapshot]

Do I need to add certain "scripts" in my package.json that I may be missing. I also tried buildpacks after watching a youtube tutorial and that did not seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was that I did not have all my files at the route. Simple as that, I just needed to delete the parent folder and move all files to the route of the directory. I had them nested within 2 folders, I had moved them out of one of those folders thinking it was at the route but it needed to go one more folder out and that was the issue that I was having.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying from Git, anything gitignored will not be included in what gets deployed. Rather than ignoring the whole public directory, you could ignore only some files, for example `public/*.js`.

EDIT: see comments, I misread the question.

Comment: right, so I do not want my public directory to be ignored nor anything within it. The error I am getting is that Heroku cannot find the index.html file within my public directory even though I am not ignoring it. I included the screenshot to show because I saw an answer to this question asking if it was ignored so I just wanted to prove that it is not being ignored. But really I want to know why Heroku can't find that index.html file.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I completely misread despite your screenshot! You mentioned buildpacks, was that the mars/create-react-app-buildpack? And did it have the same error when following these instructions? https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#create-the-heroku-app If so, an alternative might be to add a postbuild script to your package.json to move everything in /public up to the project root, but that could make a mess of your repo.

Comment: So I have not done it through that documentation through the link you posted. I connected my github and then added the link to the buildpack within the settings tab of my Heroku app. If I follow that documentation do I create a new app with "heroku create $APP_NAME --buildpack mars/create-react-app" or do I replace "$APP_NAME" with the name of my current Heroku app? - Not sure if that would make a difference or not but I am willing to try. Thank you for you help by the way!

For the postbuild script what would I add to the "scripts" object in the package.json?

Comment: In a previous version of my portfolio I had this - 
```"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  }```

Comment: `$APP_NAME` signifies that you should replace it with your app name. the `$` is a common shorthand for saying "this is a variable," as in shell script syntax. A postbuild script to move all files to the root would be `"postbuild": "mv public/* ."`, but if the buildpack works that would definitely be a better option.

Comment: I tried both but they both failed, and still has the initial error of: `Could not find a required file.
         Name: index.html
         Searched in: /tmp/build_09d879f7_/public`

Comment: Did you try both at once or separately? The error makes me think the buildpack may have been applied/configured correctly since it's now looking in /public, at least.

Comment: I could not get the build pack to configure correctly via the terminal commands. I still had it added via the settings=>buildpack=>add url, so I tried it with and without the buildpack after adding the `"postbuild": "mv public/* ."`

Comment: I'm out of ideas on this but hopeful that someone else will come across the question and think of something.

Comment: Thanks, yea I really don't know either. I'll reach out on other platforms and see if I can solve it and then I'll try to update with a resolution